# Convertir Objeto para trabajar con el Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, angular4

Estoy trabajando con Angular dos con el siguiente JSON:

```
{
    "var_TempExt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_TempIxt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempInt",
            "attrValue": "15",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempInt",
            "attrValue": "15",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempInt",
            "attrValue": "15",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        },
        {
            "attrName": "var_TempInt",
            "attrValue": "15",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_HumRExt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_HumRExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_HumRInt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_HumRInt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_RadiacionExt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_RadiacionExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_RadiacionGlobalInt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_RadiacionGlobalInt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_CO2Exterior": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_CO2Exterior",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Para registrar esta respuesta en mi front he diseñado esto:

Una clase encargada del modelo de datos con los tres atributos.

En mi component he declarado este dato:

```
miData: any = {};
```

Asignando la respuesta de tal forma:

```
            this.miData = response;
            let var_TempExt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_TempExt;
            let var_TempInt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_TempInt;
            let var_HumRExt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_HumRExt;
            let var_HumRInt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_HumRInt;
            let var_RadiacionExt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_RadiacionExt;
            let var_RadiacionGlobalInt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_RadiacionGlobalInt;
            let var_CO2Exterior: Inver[] = this.miData.var_CO2Exterior;
```

Mostrando la información por ejemplo:

```
console.log('mostramos primer log: ' + var_CO2Exterior);
```

Obtengo este resultado (un objeto con la información)

```
mostramos primer log: [object Object]
```

Utiliando:

```
        console.log('mostramos primer log: ' + JSON.stringify(var_CO2Exterior));
```

Se muestra lo que contiene ese objeto:

```
mostramos primer log: [{"attrName":"var_CO2Exterior","attrValue":"8","recvTime":"2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"}]
```

¿Como puedo extraer la información de cada variable para no tener un objeto? antes lo hacia con un for y anidando if comprobando el nombre pero est hace muy lenta la carga.

```
if (respuesta.some(inv => inv.attrName=='var_CO2Exterior')) {
  let valores= respuesta.map(inv => inv.attrValue);
  console.log(valores);
}
```

Para poder mostrar en el html {{var_CO2Exterior.value}}

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Hola @pablo estas en lo cierto el JSon recuperar de bd pero he duplicado los datos y en la ultima parte sobre sensor1 lo mismo lo copié de lo anterior que tenía.

Comment: Según entiendo, la respuesta es un objeto, no un array...¿cómo aplicas some?

Comment: Pero el somo lo hacía antes. Asignaba la respuesta a una variable y recorría esa variable y con un if iba generando un Array para cada campo. Pero cuando tienes un json de 1000datos pues no es efectivo ese método. Por eso he cambiado la repuesta de la api a todo estructurado para que me dé directamente eso y no tener que hacerlo yo.

Comment: Creo que ya te he entendido, pero me queda una duda: ¿Qué valor quieres mostrar, el de la fecha más reciente?¿Todos, en un histórico?

Comment: Pues la ultima fecha mas reciente, la idea es rellenar la información. del valor en un campo del html.

Comment: var_CO2Exterior[0].attrValue con esto si consigo el ultimo valor. Pero no se si es lo correcto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando la respuesta que recibías antes (un array con todos los datos) podrías usar Array.reduce para quedarte con el más nuevo de cada *origen* (attrName). En una sola pasada reduces el array a unos pocos atributos, con lo que funcionará bastante rápido incluso con cientos (miles) de elementos:

```js
var respuesta =[
 { "attrName": "var_TempInt", "attrValue": "15", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:56:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempInt", "attrValue": "15", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:55:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempInt", "attrValue": "15", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:58:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempInt", "attrValue": "15", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempExt", "attrValue": "8", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:54:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempExt", "attrValue": "8", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:53:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempExt", "attrValue": "8", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:50:45.000Z"},
 { "attrName": "var_TempExt", "attrValue": "8", "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"}
]

var datos= respuesta.reduce((acumulado, elem) => {
  if (!acumulado[elem.attrName]) {
    acumulado[elem.attrName]=elem;
    return acumulado;
  }
  
  let latest=new Date(acumulado[elem.attrName].recvTime);
  let current=new Date(elem.recvTime);
  if (current>latest) {
    acumulado[elem.attrName]=elem.attrValue;
  }
  return acumulado;
  
},{});

console.log(datos)
```

Se podría optimizar si la fecha estuviese en formato "Unix Time", siendo un número fácilmente comparable. Así no tendrías que crear tantos objetos Date.

Comment: pues fijate que yo creia que era mejor traerme el json ya tratado jajaj